# Google Books API always returns saleability="NOT_FOR_SALE"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-books

I am playing around with [Google Books API](https://developers.google.com/books/). I use the following jQuery code to get a book result searching by the book's ISBN:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes',
    data: {q: 'isbn:' + myIsbn, country: 'UK'},
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data){
        console.info('Google Books API retrieved:');
        console.info(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log(arguments)
    }
});
```

The problem I face is that whatever book I search for, `salesInfo.salablity` is always "NOT_FOR_SALE"

```
"saleInfo" : { "country" : "GB",
               "isEbook" : false,
               "saleability" : "NOT_FOR_SALE"
             }
```

Any ideas why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Google Developer's website](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/books/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/books/model/Volume.SaleInfo.html#setSaleability%28java.lang.String%29)

*Saleability Means:*

> Whether or not this book is available for sale or offered for free  in
>   the Google eBookstore for the country listed above. Possible values
>   are FOR_SALE, FREE, NOT_FOR_SALE, or FOR_PREORDER.  The value returned
>   may be null

possibly, the book you are searching for might not be available( **on Google eBookstore**) for sale in the country you are searching for.

Comment: I can't find a single book that would return a price. Actually all I need is the publisher's cover price (the one listed on the book). Is there any other API I can use for that?

Comment: I tried with some of the books listed in Google eBookstore, I chose US for country param and I managed to retrieve the price. Thanks.